# Applying multiple "or" filters using Query by Example

Tags: c#, active-directory, directoryservices, query-by-example

I'm trying to retrieve a set of records from Active Directory using Query by Example. This snippet will find any records with the name of "John Smith":

```
 PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, contextName);
 User filter = new User(context);
 var users = new List<User>();            
 filter.LastName = "Smith";
 filter.GivenName = "John";
 PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> matches = null;            
 PrincipalSearcher searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(filter);
 matches = searcher.FindAll() as PrincipalSearchResult<Principal>;
```

but I want to apply these filters so I can match any record with a last name of "Smith" **or** a given name of "John", e.g. "Mary Smith", "John Brown". Is this possible using Query by Example - without having to run multiple searches? I haven't been able to find any documented examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do any type of OR searching with QBE (Query by Example).

You *can* write an LDAP query with all the OR's and AND's you want, run that query separately, get back the distinguished names, and then look up all the matching UserContext objects...  I know, it sucks.

There are a lot of areas where not much consideration was given when the AccountManagement structure was put together.